# VarStringToOleStr in _vararrayput. Why?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, variant

Why in the procedure _vararrayput of the unit Variants do invoke
procedure VarStringToOleStr.
This method is called when assigning a variable of type Variant to element of  variants array. The fact is that in Delphi <= 7 string type using for blob. And this approach is used in the components of ODAC.